# Word VBA - How to delete TimeStamp in Footer?

Tags: vba, ms-word

How do I delete a timestamp in a word footer using VBA?

I do not know what the timestamp says. Only that there is a DD/MM/YYYY timestamp.

There is other content in the footer, besides the timestamp, that I do not want to be deleted.

The timestamp is part of a statement in one cell of the only table in the footer

I have tried editing the range of text in the footer, but it only breaks the document. I don't think you can do this on footers from my experience:

```
Dim footr As Word.HeaderFooter
For Each footr In ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Footers
    'With footr.Range
        If footr.Range.Text <> "" Then
            footr.Range.Delete unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=-20
        End If
    'End With
Next footr
```

Along the same lines, is there a way to search with wildcards in the footer? If so, that would be an easy fix. I have tried using wildcards but it didn't work on footer text.... maybe I was doing it wrong?

Comment: I think you should have Count:=20 , not Count:=-20. Otherwise, you might have a problem if for example the timestamp is in a locked content control, i.e. you would have to unlock the control before deleting it.

Comment: Is the timestamp a fixed text that was added at a certain time, or is it a field that is updated (eg when printing or saving the document)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Assumes the timestamp is the only content in footers, and no table in footers

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub RemoveFooter()
    Dim oSec As Section
    For Each oSec In ActiveDocument.Sections
        oSec.Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Text = ""
    Next
End Sub
```

---

*Update:*

> Question: The timestamp is part of a statement in one cell of the only table in the footer

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub RemoveTimeStamp()
    Dim oSec As Section, oRng As Range
    For Each oSec In ActiveDocument.Sections
        Set oRng = oSec.Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range
        With oRng.Find
            .ClearFormatting
            .MatchWildcards = True
            .Text = "[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4}"
            .Replacement.ClearFormatting
            .Replacement.Text = ""
            .Execute Replace:=Word.wdReplaceAll
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Updated the post for clarity, thanks.

Comment: Please try the updated code.